# Will the previous stay outside USA add to the current stay? Or will the 6 month clock start over?

Tags: usa, greencard

I got my green card this year. I left the US for 37 days and came back. Now in December I wish to leave the US for five and a half months, approximately 175 to 170 days, which is less than six months. Can I go for this duration? Will my previous 37 days be added to this, which would make my absence more than 6 months total?

Comment: Which "6-month clock" are you referring to?

Comment: @user102008 probably [8 USC 1101(a)(13)(C)(ii)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#a_13_C_ii).

Answer (score 5):

According to [this page](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/820/%7E/can-a-u.s.-lawful-permanent-resident-leave-multiple-times-and-return) from the US Customs and Border Protection, you can stay out of the US for up to a year before you run into problems.

(I found other, non-authoritative, sites which suggest you may be subject to additional questioning between six months and a year.)

I think you will be fine.

Comment: Just in case the people who think there may be additional questioning are right, the OP could carry evidence that they really are resident in the US and only visiting other places.

Comment: The "additional questioning" arises from [8 USC 1101(a)(13)(C)(ii)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#a_13_C_ii), which specifies that LPRs arriving after an absence of over 180 days must be considered "as seeking an admission"; in general, returning LPRs are not considered as such.